# admob dependency problem while dependency gradle finished

Tags: android-gradle-plugin, dependency-management

when I gradle  the ad mob dependency the project file shows the below error..

```
**Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.0-beta1) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-beta1] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-41
is also present at [com.android.support:customtabs:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:25:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:44 to override.
```

**

**dependency of ad mob  that I used**

*implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.2.0'*

---

I can't figure out this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it tells you not to use `26.0.0-beta1`. this is most likely not the least related to AdMob and without the `build.gradle`, this question is even difficult to answer. "I can't figure out this problem. Thanks in advance." is rather irrelevant, while withholding relevant information. the problem is, that the package you've declared to be the problem, isn't the problem. and don't use tag `android-studio` for Gradle problems.